# how to generalize an interface to require a return value of some tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++11

I am using the SOCI library which has good support for [boost and std::tuple<>](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/boost.html).

My intention is to define a **abstract interface** called `SOCI_Streamable` which requires a method that returns **some tuple**.

I have it working for a **specific tuple** in gcc 4.7.2, but I need help abstracting this interface to work for **any tuple**.

*In other words, I would like to convert this requirement into code:  a class satisfies the requirements for `SOCI_Streamable` if it can return some kind of std::tuple - I don't care what kind.*

A significant change in the code below is fine, as long as it satisfies the requirement.  I suspect some kind of template code or maybe even CRTP is required, but I'm not sure.

```
#include<tuple>

// want to generalize next line to any std::tuple<>
typedef std::tuple<int const&,char const> some_tuple;    

class SOCI_Streamable
{
public:
  virtual some_tuple obj_as_tuple() const = 0; 
};

class Foo :
    public SOCI_Streamable
{
public:
  virtual some_tuple obj_as_tuple() const 
    {
        return std::forward_as_tuple( m_int, m_char );
    }
private:
    int   m_int;
    char  m_char;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
}
```

Comment: can you specify the types at the implementing class level?

Comment: @KarthikT sure, but the problem is still tying that to some abstract interface at the interface level...  ...if you have an idea how to do that, please post an answer - ty

Comment: Do you want to be able to cast the object to SOCI_Streamable and then call the interface? I can't see how you could do that, because the return type couldn't be known at compile-time. Or are you ok with the base class being some templated instantiation of SOCI_Streamable?

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class A,class B>
class SOCI_Streamable
{
public:
  typedef std::tuple<A,B> Tuple;
  virtual Tuple obj_as_tuple() const = 0; 
};

class Foo :
   public SOCI_Streamable<int const&,char const>
{
```

If you can specify the types at the implementer level, this should work. But that does change the single interface into a family of interfaces.. let me see if there is a better way
.